# Powershell using PadLeft method X Null-Valued Expression

Tags: powershell

Need help to fix an error I´m getting:

$InputFile:

```
JKAFDHLFEWQR,AFLJHDJB7269367,100.000000,13/01/2017
AKDSNIVVXCOI,ASJDFGYQTWEYTRS,100.000000,08/06/2017
POASDJFHDHFJ,PAOSDFPOIK12311,98.500000,08/06/2017
NIUCIADFUASD,KLJFGUWYE89,100.150000,15/02/2017
NACSDHFIUDYD,ASDFMJKH124,100.150000,02/12/2015
QWERYEUYREOQ,JDFSJ62736J,100.150000,04/12/2015
UQER76786ADS,MCVKJDUAFIO,100.150000,01/02/2016
NMCXHJKSDH67,ZNKSOQ,10.000000,13/04/2016
MAOJI2637868,BNIISA,10.000000,04/04/2016
CMASDHFUIQE1,AMSTER,10.000000,04/04/2016
JSFHIEUWRYJF,POQERUANSHJKSHD,100.000000,19/12/2016
23KJDKH7SD67,MKOAUSDUIFOIUQW,100.000000,12/12/2016
```

Expected result: (space + 0 + spaces + array[0] + content of array[2] with leading zeroes)

```
 0                   JKAFDHLFEWQR 0000000000000100.000000
 0                   AKDSNIVVXCOI 0000000000000100.000000
 0                   POASDJFHDHFJ 0000000000000098.500000
 0                   NIUCIADFUASD 0000000000000100.150000
 0                   NACSDHFIUDYD 0000000000000100.150000
 0                   QWERYEUYREOQ 0000000000000100.150000
 0                   UQER76786ADS 0000000000000010.000000
 0                   NMCXHJKSDH67 0000000000000010.000000
 0                   MAOJI2637868 0000000000000010.000000
 0                   CMASDHFUIQE1 0000000000000010.000000
 0                   JSFHIEUWRYJF 0000000000000100.000000
 0                   23KJDKH7SD67 0000000000000100.000000
```

My Code:

```
gc $InputFile | ForEach-Object {

  $Value = $_ -split ','

  $Val2 = $Value[2] | % PadLeft 23 '0'

  $FileOut += $19spaces + $Value[0] + " " + $Val2 + "`n"

}

$FileOut.Split("`n") + $LastLine | Out-File $OutFile
```

The $LastLine adds a trailing line at the end:

```
 0                    0000000000000000.000000
```

The code gives me exactly what I need however I´m getting this error message:

> % : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At
>   C:\Desktop\test.ps1:92 char:23
>   +   $Val2 = $Value[2] | % PadLeft 23 '0'
>   +                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumen tException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
>      .ForEachObjectCommand

Any idea on how to fix this error please? Thanks all!

Comment: Do you have trailing lines at the end of your file? Or some empty lines

Comment: Not clear now if you have a formatting issue, or an exception with the code.

Comment: No no, the formatting is working fine, only the exception is the problem. Please ignore the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could find to reproduce this issue is by adding extra lines in the content of `$InputFile`

To fix it just verify that what is returned by the split is not $null

```
$Value = $_ -split ','

if ($value -ne $null)
{
   $Val2 = $Value[2] | % PadLeft 23 '0'

   $FileOut += $19spaces + $Value[0] + " " + $Val2 + "`n"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Micky Balladelli, the if made the trick! The exception is not showing up anymore. :D

Answer (score 2):

This PowerShell one liner should do with

- Import-csv and manually supplied headers H1..H4
- the [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html):

---

```
> import-csv .\input.txt -header H1,H2,H3,H4|%{" {0,-20}{1} {2}" -f 0,$_.H1,$_.H3.PadLeft(23,'0')}
 0                   JKAFDHLFEWQR 0000000000000100.000000
 0                   AKDSNIVVXCOI 0000000000000100.000000
 0                   POASDJFHDHFJ 0000000000000098.500000
 0                   NIUCIADFUASD 0000000000000100.150000
 0                   NACSDHFIUDYD 0000000000000100.150000
 0                   QWERYEUYREOQ 0000000000000100.150000
 0                   UQER76786ADS 0000000000000100.150000
 0                   NMCXHJKSDH67 0000000000000010.000000
 0                   MAOJI2637868 0000000000000010.000000
 0                   CMASDHFUIQE1 0000000000000010.000000
 0                   JSFHIEUWRYJF 0000000000000100.000000
 0                   23KJDKH7SD67 0000000000000100.000000
```

No issues with trailing blank lines.

Comment: Cool @LotPings, as I´m new to Powershell did not think about the import-csv but appreciate the tip, it works good too. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pipeline the text to PadLeft.

```
$Val2 = $Value[2].PadLeft(23, '0')
```